# ruby selenium (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll

How to scroll to elements to avoid getting such error, I use trick with

```
browser.action.send_keys(:page_down)
              .perform
```

and it finds elements, is there any other way to scroll into view ?

I tried `location_once_scrolled_into_view`, but can't get how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll into view of an element via `execute_script()`:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Comment: Thanks and it works, scroll to elements as expected!

Comment: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element) works for me.